# What is meant by the wedge product?

Tags: differential-geometry, exterior-algebra

I have encountered two definitions of the wedge product. The first is the exterior product as seen on the wikipedia page for "exterior algebra". It is a map $\wedge:\Lambda(V) \times \Lambda(V) \to \Lambda(V)$, so it is defined for pairs of alternating tensors of any ranks.

I have also seen a map $\wedge:A_k(V) \times A_l(V) \to A_{k + l}(V)$ defined for tensors of fixed ranks. I believe this was in Loring Tu's *Introduction to Manifolds*.

I guess I'm wondering which of these is more common, if they're ever differentiated or if there are commonly accepted names that distinguish the two, and what I should think about when I see $f \wedge g$ somewhere.

Comment: "what I should think about when I see $f \wedge g$ somewhere" Presumably this is clarified either before or immediately after you encounter it.

Comment: You could call the first the product in the exterior algebra, and the second the restriction of that product to the $(k, l)$-graded component. But unless you were specifically using that second map on its own, I don't think many people would bother distinguishing between the two at all.

Comment: @C.F.G The question is more about terminology. I know what the equational definition of the wedge product is.